# Zeros of a complex function

Tags: cv.complex-variables

I wonder whether $\sum_{k=0}^n \exp(r_k z)$ has a complex zero for any $n\in \mathbb{Z}_n^*,0=r_0<r_1<r_2<\dotsb<r_n$. I think the answer is affirmative.

Comment: Not for $n=0$, no.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An affirmative answer follows from (9) in [this paper by Ritt](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1929-031-04/S0002-9947-1929-1501506-6/S0002-9947-1929-1501506-6.pdf).

Answer (score 20):

A simpler proof can be obtained as follows. Proving by contradiction, suppose it has no zeros. Since this is an entire function of order one, it must be $\exp(az+b)$.
So we have the identity
$$\sum_{k=0}^n e^{r_kz}=e^{az+b},$$
where all $r_k$ are distinct. If $a\not\in\{ r_k\}$,
this gives a linear dependence of $n+2$ exponential functions.
If $a\in\{ r_k\}$, this gives a linear dependence of $n+1$ exponential functions. But it is well-known and easy to prove
(using Wronskian determinant) that exponential functions with
distinct exponents are linearly independent.

Remark. A little more work shows that in fact such a sum
has infinitely many zeros, moreover the sequence of zeros has
non-zero density: the number of zeros in disks $|z|\leq r$
is at least $cr$ for some $c>0$.

Comment: Beautiful proof.